# Accessing exported function of a service from the same service in SailsJS

Tags: sails.js

I have exported a service as getProdDetailsBatch and another as createNewCartMysql in the same file MySQLService.js. Below is the definition for the same.

```
exports.getProdDetailsBatch = function(prod_list, city_id){
   var defer = sails.Q.defer();
//Process Request
   return defer.promise;
}


exports.createNewCartMysql = function(product_id, qty, cart_type_id, member_id, visitor_id, city_id){
   var defer = sails.Q.defer();
//Process Request

   getProdDetailsBatch([], 1).then(function(){

   })

   return defer.promise;
}
```

While I am able to use the service getProdDetailsBatch from all other services in different file as well as from the controllers, but not createNewCartMysql which has been defined in the same file.

Would someone have an idea as how to access the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try instead:

```
module.exports = {
  getProdDetailsBatch: function(){
    ...
  },
  createNewCartMysql: function(){
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Works great!

Answer (score 0):

Actually got it working after some random trials:

```
exports.<name of the function>
```

Above is accessible globally.

Answer (score 0):

That will also work smooth if you replace **exports** with **module.exports**.
Example:

```
module.exports.getProdDetailsBatch = function(prod_list, city_id){
   var defer = sails.Q.defer();
//Process Request
   return defer.promise;
};


module.exports.createNewCartMysql = function(product_id, qty, cart_type_id, member_id, visitor_id, city_id){
   var defer = sails.Q.defer();
//Process Request

   getProdDetailsBatch([], 1).then(function(){

   })

   return defer.promise;
}
```